# Tile updater Windows 8 simulator exception

Tags: c#, windows-8, tile, microsoft-metro

I create a windows 8 application, with live tiles and when I run in windows8 working fine, but when I run in simulator I get this exception:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in myapp.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The notification platform doesn't have appropriate privilege on resources. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0117)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft answer:

> this is a known issue in with the notification platform (which
>   updates tiles) and a bug has already been filed.  I'm going to mark
>   this as answered and move to the the tools forum.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to where you found this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/8e67cda3-5b6a-4b7e-a95f-cf74cc7cdf54/ (first google result)

Comment: it's the same "this is a known issue in with th"

Answer (score 1):

The word that jumps out is 'privilages'
Have you tried running VS in Elevated Mode?
Also, put a try catch statement around that line code.

Comment: the try catch is not a solution, i need this method to run